# Docker Redhat Build Error: Unable to find a match: boost-program-options

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, redhat

Im trying to install the mariadb on a redhat container. I am following [this guide on their website](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-install-mariadb-on-rhel8-centos8/)

```
# Base image
FROM redhat/ubi8:latest

# Get latest packages
RUN dnf update \
    && dnf install curl -y

# Add MariaDB 10.10 repository
RUN curl -LsS -O https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
# RUN bash mariadb_repo_setup --mariadb-server-version=10.4
RUN bash mariadb_repo_setup 
RUN dnf install perl-DBI libaio libsepol lsof boost-program-options
RUN dnf install --repo="mariadb-main" MariaDB-server
```

When building the image I get the following error: `Error: Unable to find a match: boost-program-options`.

Here is the full output for reference:

```
docker build -t sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
 Step 1/6 : FROM redhat/ubi8:latest 
  ---> 36660eab1ea3
 Step 2/6 : RUN dnf update     && dnf install curl -y 
  ---> Running in d6bf46db2889
 Updating Subscription Management repositories.
 Subscription Manager is operating in container mode.

 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS  4.3 MB/s | 836 kB     00:00    
 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStre  12 MB/s | 3.2 MB     00:00    
 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeRea 277 kB/s |  30 kB     00:00    
 Dependencies resolved.
 Nothing to do.
 Complete

 Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Fri Mar 24 19:37:39 2023.
 Package curl-7.61.1-25.el8_7.3.x86_64 is already installed.
 Dependencies resolved.
 Nothing to do.
 Complete!
 Removing intermediate container d6bf46db2889
  ---> 4684d80eaa91
 Step 3/6 : RUN curl -LsS -O https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup 
  ---> Running in dda26279211e
 Removing intermediate container dda26279211e
  ---> d12aecebca09
 Step 4/6 : RUN bash mariadb_repo_setup 
  ---> Running in 4d471485f953
 # [info] Checking for script prerequisites.
 # [info] MariaDB Server version 10.11 is valid
 # [info] Repository file successfully written to /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo
 # [info] Adding trusted package signing keys...
 /etc/pki/rpm-gpg /
 /
 # [info] Successfully added trusted package signing keys
 # [info] Cleaning package cache...

 25 files removed
 Removing intermediate container 4d471485f953
  ---> 53bbdd28131e
 Step 5/6 : RUN dnf install perl-DBI libaio libsepol lsof boost-program-options 
  ---> Running in 44043756b0d6

 MariaDB Server                                  838 kB/s | 483 kB     00:00    
 MariaDB MaxScale                                 18 kB/s | 8.4 kB     00:00    
 MariaDB Tools                                   6.7 kB/s | 4.4 kB     00:00    
 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS  4.8 MB/s | 836 kB     00:00    
 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStre  10 MB/s | 3.2 MB     00:00    
 Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeRea 277 kB/s |  30 kB     00:00    
 Package libsepol-2.9-3.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
 No match for argument: boost-program-options
 Error: Unable to find a match: boost-program-options
 
Failed to build image: The command '/bin/sh -c dnf install perl-DBI libaio libsepol lsof boost-program-options' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Edit:** I found [this guide](https://installati.one/centos/8/boost-program-options/) and updated the list then applied but it results in the same error.

```
RUN dnf makecache --refresh
RUN dnf -y install boost-program-options
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to finally build using rockylinux8.

I created a `mariadb-rhel8.repo` file which poitns to mariadb 10.7 rhel8:

```
# MariaDB 10.7 RedHatEnterpriseLinux repository list - created 2023-03-24 20:54 UTC
# https://mariadb.org/download/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
# rpm.mariadb.org is a dynamic mirror if your preferred mirror goes offline. See https://mariadb.org/mirrorbits/ for details.
# baseurl = https://rpm.mariadb.org/10.7/rhel/$releasever/$basearch
baseurl = https://mirrors.xtom.com/mariadb/yum/10.7/rhel/$releasever/$basearch
module_hotfixes = 1
# gpgkey = https://rpm.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgkey = https://mirrors.xtom.com/mariadb/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck = 1
```

Then ran this Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM rockylinux:8.7

# add repos
COPY mariadb-rhel8.repo /etc/yum.repods.d/
RUN yum repolist

# Get latest packages
RUN dnf update -y \
    && dnf install curl -y

# Add MariaDB 10.10 repository
RUN curl -LsS -O https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
RUN bash mariadb_repo_setup --mariadb-server-version=10.7
RUN dnf install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client -y

# clean up yum
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```